# Can Odata service be hosted as windows service?

Tags: windows-services, odata

I wanted to know if an Odata service can be hosted as a windows service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely possible. The question is what server technology you want to use. If you want to use WCF Data Services, then it supports custom hosting. See this description to start with: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668805.aspx

Comment: ok thanks!! ill check on that...was trying with self hosting as a console app but didn't know how to host it as a windows service.